# Using reference in replace-regexp

Tags: regular-expressions

What should I type in replace-regexp command to change the first list below into the second? I'd like to repeat each number at the beginning of line. To achieve that, I assume that I'll have to refer to each regexp match when I type what I'd like to replace each of them with, but how can I do that?

```
* apple
12
* banana
5
* grape
5
* watermelon
3



* apple
12 12
* banana
5 5
* grape
5 5
* watermelon
3 3
```

Comment: I found the answer here, but my question's title seems really different than the one in the link. Should I close this as a duplicate?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003774/emacs-how-to-replace-a-string-using-a-regular-expression

Comment: No. Only duplicates of other questions on the same site are closed. It's OK for duplicates to exist on different sites. The question you cite is on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace (i.e. `M-x query-replace-regexp`)

```
^\([[:digit:]]+\)
```

with

```
\1 \1
```

viola. You can look up [this decent reference](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression).